# Android 8.x notifications : how to avoid the fade in/fade out of the notifications over my app when my app is open ?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

When the user performs some specific actions in my app (while my app is open and visible full screen by the user), it creates a notification with some useful information.

Nevertheless, I want this notification to be visible only in the notification tray. I don't want that it fades in/out from the top of the screen over my app while the user is using the app (like it worked before on Android lower than 8).

I have got this problem on Android 8 with the new kind of notifications using the notification channel.

So, how to avoid the fade in/fade out of the notifications (created by my app) over my app when my app is open ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that _your_ notification or from other apps? What level of importance your channel has?

Comment: I speak about my notification. I don't care about being bothered by the notifications of other apps. I tried all the notification importances => no importance level allowed to remove the fade in/fade out of my notifs over my app. Any other idea ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's odd: low importance notifications are said to not produce "peeks". What fade are we talking about? Where have you tested this? Can you share some relevant code?

Comment: See my answer to my own question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, to other part of your question, i.e. "How can I make it so there is no fade when user is on specific screen" - you will need to post your notification to a separate channel when that specific screen is opened. As far as I can tell - there's not really any way other than doing it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the importance of the notification channel to IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT.

But, I noticed that to test properly the changes in the channel parameters, I have to uninstall/install the app and also potentially to change temporarly the name of the channel ID.

To avoid some strange bugs on the notifications (e.g. : notification showing with fading in/out from top even with IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT,  sound on the notif even with IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT, etc...) I had change my project target from 26 to 27.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uninstalling is not requied, I think. You can also make a temporary button somewhere in your menus that would call `removeChannel` and then `createChannel` with new parameters. Should work as expected. Alternatively, you as a user can set the importance level in application options using System Settings. [Channels doc](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) has a passage about this.